# ¿Cómo obtener un datos de una lista de tuplas?

Tags: python, nltk

Hola soy nuevo en python y mucho mas nuevo usando nltk, obtener un valor especifico de una lista de tuplas
Mi codigo es el siguiente

```
pal = "love"
lista = [pal]
d = {}
d[lista[0]] =[]


prueba = [('fast', 'AN'),('Zero',"NN"),('hint','PN')]
for t in list(prueba):
    temp = prueba[t][1]
    d[lista[0]].append(temp)
print(prueba)

for t in d.keys():
    print(t, d[t])
```

quiero obtener todos los segundos datos de las tuplas, o sea AN, NN y PN estoy intentando hacerlo con el ciclo pero por alguna razon me sale el siguiete error
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Answer (score 1):

Usando comprensión de listas, puedes reformular una nueva lista con los segundos elementos de cada tupla:

```
l = [v for w, v in [('fast', 'AN'),('Zero',"NN"),('hint','PN')]]
print(l)

['AN', 'NN', 'PN']
```

Answer (score 0):

La manera que puedes usar para obtener los segundos items de cada tupla es esta:

```
prueba = [('fast', 'AN'),('Zero',"NN"),('hint','PN')]

for item in prueba:
    print(item[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Si bien hay muy buenas respuestas acá en como lograr la implementación que buscas, creo que la mejor solución es la que te explique qué estás haciendo mal y porqué obtienes ese error, así puedes aprender de él ya que nos indicas que estás empezando a aprender a programar en Python.

El error que obtienes:

> error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Es porque cuando haces:

```
for t in list(prueba):
    temp = prueba[t][1]
    d[lista[0]].append(temp)
```

Estas confundiendo `t` con un índice que lleva la cuenta de los elementos en lista, cuando en realidad es un elemento completo de la lista, por ejemplo en el primera iteración `t` va a tener el valor de la tupla  `('fast', 'AN')` y no un valor entero de `0`.

Entonces al hacer `prueba[t]` estás cómo dice el error anterior, tratando de usar como índice para una lista algo que no es un entero o un slice... Estas usando una tupla, lo cual Python no sabe cómo interpretar o ejecutar.

Espero que con esta explicación puedas entender que es lo que está pasando y ayude a tu proceso de aprendizaje con Python.

Si quieres implementar tu código de la manera en la que lo tratabas de hacer anteriormente la manera correcta sería:

```
for t in list(prueba):
    temp = t[1]
    d[lista[0]].append(temp)
```

O todavía más sencillo y descriptivo:

```
for miTupla in list(prueba):
    d[lista[0]].append(miTupla[1])
```